# Testing Qt Application in VirtualBox

Tags: qt, opengl, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I wrote Application in Qt. It works fine in Win 8.1 64 bit, that is installed on my PC. But I would like to test it also in other OS. So I wanted to use free Virtual Machines in https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/ and test Application on VirtualBox.

But when I wanted to run my application in Win7 32 bit VirtualBox, I get following error:

```
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenFramebuffers'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenFramebuffersOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenFramebuffersARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenFramebuffersEXT'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenRenderbuffers'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenRenderbuffersOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenRenderbuffersARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenRenderbuffersEXT'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindRenderbuffer'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindRenderbufferOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindRenderbufferARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindRenderbufferEXT'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glRenderbufferStorage'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glRenderbufferStorageOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glRenderbufferStorageARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glRenderbufferStorageEXT'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenRenderbuffers'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenRenderbuffersOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenRenderbuffersARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenRenderbuffersEXT'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindRenderbuffer'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindRenderbufferOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindRenderbufferARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindRenderbufferEXT'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glRenderbufferStorage'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glRenderbufferStorageOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glRenderbufferStorageARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glRenderbufferStorageEXT'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glFramebufferRenderbuffer'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glFramebufferRenderbufferOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glFramebufferRenderbufferARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glFramebufferRenderbuffer'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glFramebufferRenderbufferOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glFramebufferRenderbufferARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffers'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glGenBuffersEXT'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferData'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferDataOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferDataARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBufferDataEXT'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBuffer'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferOES'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glBindBufferEXT'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgram'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramObject'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateProgramObjectARB'
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program 
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShader'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderARB'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObject'
getProcAddress: Unable to resolve 'glCreateShaderObjectARB'
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader 
Renderer failed shader compilation:
```

I know that it is problem with OpenGL.

Is it possible to forward somehow OpenGL from my PC to VirtualBox. Because on my PC I have no problem with OpenGL.

Or, is it tottaly crazy thing to test Qt Application in VirtualBox?

Comment: Do you use openGL? It looks like it tries to find some OpenGL dependencies and finds they are not there.

Comment: @JohnKeates Yes, Qt uses OpenGL. And it looks like VirtualBox doesn't provide such Graphic feature.

Comment: What steps have you taken to deploy the application?

Comment: @MrEricSir I used https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows. But Errors I get only by installed complete Qt with Creator and by running Qt Application project. Without Installed Qt, Application didn't launched, without any errors.

Comment: May be this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56857915/2672125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install VirtualBox Guest Additions
2. Check Enable 3D Acceleation

Comment: This would have been my suggestion as well ;-) OpenGL should normally work with software-only rendering, so the error is strange as-is, but enabling  graphics acceleration will enable OpenGL hardware rendering as well.